# Resolving Razor javascript @Url.Content prototype pattern

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a ASP.NET MVC View (Razor) and at the end of the file I load in a section some javascript:

```
@section FooterScripts{

    <script>
        $(function () {
            // creates the data table
            var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Accounting/GetListAccounts")/';
        });
    </script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/pages/list-account.js"></script>

}
```

Here the variable `ajaxUrl` is resolved so the variable will get the value: 
[image]

Now, `list-account.js` uses prototype pattern and has something like this:

```
! function($) {
    "use strict";

    var ListAccount = function() {
        this.$window = $(window)
    };


    ListAccount.prototype.start = function() {
            var $this = this;

            var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Accounting/GetListAccounts")/';

        },
        //init
        $.ListAccount = new ListAccount, $.ListAccount.Constructor = ListAccount
}(window.jQuery),

//initializing
function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.ListAccount.start();
}(window.jQuery);
```

My problem is that here the variable `ajaxUrl` doesn't get resolved. Seems like in order to `Razor` to resolve `@Url.Content` the variable should be inside the code.

> Any workaround or solution so my `prototype javascript` file gets the @Url.Content resolved?

Comment: Razor code is not parsed in external files.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I declare that variable before and pass it to the file?

Comment: Sure. So long as `var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Accounting/GetListAccounts")/';` is in the main view, you can then just use `ajaxUrl` in the external file

Comment: Of you could have a (say) `Initialise(url)` function in the external file and pass it that way if you did not want a global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the razor in javascript, you must write the js code in the `.cshtml` file , as your case, you can set the ajaxUrl as a global variable and call it in your `.js` file, something like below:

**in index.cshtml file**

```
<script>
var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Accounting/GetListAccounts")/';
</script>
```

and you can direct to use ajaxUrl in your **list-account.js** file now